# Apache Spark 1.6: Querying single partitions leads to attributes missing error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

In my Spark 1.6 application, I have some code to choose partition and query only the given partition. I do this using:

```
val rdd = df.rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter else Iterator(), true)
val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, df.schema)
```

If I then call a UDF together with a new mapPartitions call on a field, as in

```
newDF.withColumn("newField", myUDF(df("oldField")).mapPartitions(...)
```

I get a

```
resolved attribute(s) oldField#36 missing from idField#51L,oldField#52 in operator !Project [idField#51L,oldField#52,UDF(oldField#36) AS newField#53];
```

To me it seems as the field "oldField" is somehow present, but - maybe because I created a new DataFrame? - with a wrong id (compare `oldField#52` and `oldField#36`). If I print the schema, of my old DataFrame and `newDF`, both look the same.

What can I do to avoid this error (except changing the order of the operations in the code, which I do not really like to do as the current structure seems pretty useful to me)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bind the name to the `DataFrame` which is not longer in scope. You can use [`col` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$):

```
newDF.withColumn("newField", myUDF(col("oldField"))
```

[implicit conversions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$$StringToColumn):

```
newDF.withColumn("newField", myUDF($"oldField"))
```

or current `DataFrame`:

```
newDF.withColumn("newField", myUDF(newDF("oldField"))
```